# How to register iOS device token in aws sns to receive push notifications?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

I'm using AWS push notification to send notifications ios devices. in iOS, im still unable to register device token in AWS and i can send notifications via AWS console only. please guide me how to register token in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken delegate.

I just want to send direct notifications to particular ios device...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

you should write here:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:       (NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings     settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                                                        UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                                                        UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
return YES;
```

}

Comment: Hi huoh, I just want to register iOS device token to amazon web services(aws)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking out the Mobile Hub, create a project with the Push feature configured and then download the sample app.

Additionally you can checkout the SNS documentation directly http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-apns.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do in AWS SNS:

1. Create a topic
2. Create an endpoint using the device token
3. Subscribe the endpoint to the topic created
4. Publish your message to the topic

there are more details for each point, but that's the big picture.